# Android: How to direct to another page?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Hey awesome coding geniuses! I'm a student doing my final year project and i need some help. I hope you coding geniuses can help!
I want to direct my Login.java page to my Camera.java once i click the login button. My xml page is Login.xml and Camera.xml respectively.

So this is my Login.java

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;
    private TextView attempts;
    private Button login;
    int counter = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    public void login(View view){
        if(username.getText().toString().equals("amirul") && 
              password.getText().toString().equals("aswa")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials, Please try again.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
            counter--;
            attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            if(counter==0){
                login.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And this is my Camera.java

```
public class Camera extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takephoto);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);              

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode ==0) {
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you people can help me! And this is my first post btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the password is right, You can simple start it with an intent in Your login method:

```
if(username.getText().toString().equals("amirul") && 
  password.getText().toString().equals("aswa")){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   Intent startCamIntent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
    startActivity(startCamIntent);
 }
```

And don´t forget to register the Activity inside Your manifest:

```
  <activity android:name=".Camera" />
```

To register:

- open Android Manifest
- select Applications Tab
- select "Add"
- select Activity
- at the right side click "Browse"

wait some seconds and Your Camera Activity should appear. Choose it and save it it...finished

If you use Eclipse, you don't need to register the activity in the AndroidManifest, because it does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your login method you can do something like this :

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
startActivity(cameraIntent);
```

Assuming that you have a CameraActivity.

Answer (score 0):

you need to just start intent that is consumed by camera on login button click:

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//validate username and pwd
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Camera.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the people rejecting my edits i will post it right here (as i cannot comment because i have not enough points to)

To add on Opiatefuchs, when you are using Eclipse you don't need to register the newly created activity's because Eclipse does this for you.

This comes straight from the android dev site:

All activities must be declared in your manifest file, AndroidManifest.xml, using an `<activity>` element.

When you use the Eclipse tools to create the activity, it creates a default entry. If you're using a different IDE, you need to add the manifest entry yourself.